# How can I repair loose stucco?

Tags: exterior, masonry, stucco

Less than 2 years ago I had the walls of my terrace painted, and in less than 2 years there are parts that are already like this. Is there anything I can do?

Any material?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming this is outside, it would be just rot. "Dry rot" is a misnomer in most cases. However, plaster doesn't rot (at least in an organic sense).

Comment: Bad stucco isn't the fault of the paint. Paint can't fix a bad substrate, though millions of slumlords and homeowners keep trying to think it will.

Comment: 1- the mesh wire is missing under the stucco. 2- the black water barrier paper is missing. Water is coming from above creating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like [spalling](https://www.robsonforensic.com/articles/concrete-spalling-expert-article).

The correct way to fix this is to hire a qualified concrete restoration contractor to take a look at it. They will give you an estimate to fix it. **You must find and fix the water intrusion issue first.**

Water is intruding from inside the wall or coming from above. Water will take the path of least resistance to get behind the paint film and cause delamination. Even an invisible pin hole will allow water to come in.

Once you get the water issue fixed, when you hire a contractor, insist on 1 coat of primer and 2 coats of a 20-30 mil Elastomeric. No matter the method of application, ie: spraying or rolling, insist that they backroll.
This consists of applying a roller application immediately behind the first application.

I have managed a retail paint store for 21 years and have seen this issue thousands of times. I live on the Gulf Coast, and it is a frequent problem.
It is not the paint coating.